# "To be provided" in context

Tags: grammaticality, phrasing

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> “you can contact John Doe to be provided with the account information”?

Is the *“to be provided”* part something a native English speaker would say it in this context?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's ungrammatical, strictly speaking.  However,  the active voice in "can contact" contrasted with the passive voice in "to be provided with" is a bit confusing.  If I had to say something similar, I would replace it with

> You can contact John Doe to obtain the account information.